# how to do pruning in prolog to prevent child node from generating it's parent node again

Tags: prolog

Say i have a search tree and i am trying to find all the solutions to a goal. if i do not prune the tree such that the child is still allowed to generate it's parent node the search space becomes very large. So can someone please show me a predicate that does this or explain to me how it can be done as I'm very new to Prolog.

Comment: search for `Prolog cut` i.e. !

Comment: @chac: Note that the Question asks "to find all the solutions to a goal".  Also a cut would not prevent infinite looping.

Comment: @hardmath: yes I see, but it's not clear to me is the OP already knows about !

Comment: to be able to prune your search space and still find all the solutions, you will have to use some additional knowledge about your problem domain, i.e. use heuristics. To prevent looping (if that is your problem) "blind", you can use iterative deepening. Give us some more information.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach is probably to add an extra argument to your "search" predicate which keeps track of the nodes (parent, child, etc.) already visited, plus a clause that prohibits visiting a previous node.

Some terminology is worth clearing up.  A tree is a graph without cycles (loops), so in a "search tree" you actually don't have the potential of revisiting a node twice.

Probably you are finding a path of some kind to a goal, and the solutions are the possible paths.  The stated requirement of finding "all the solutions to a goal" is in some tension with the exclusion of those paths which do revisit nodes more than once.  However let's assume the restriction of not revisiting nodes is allowed.

If you supplied more in the way of how you coded your search predicate, I'd be able to illustrate concretely how to add the extra "list already visited" argument.